# ClearTimeout with condition is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

Does any one know why this is not working?

http://jsfiddle.net/jonevar/2Z2NQ/5/

Here is the whole code:

```
function ag_alert(message) {

    event.preventDefault();

    //SetTimeout in case didn't close manualy
    var timer = setTimeout(cls_message, 5000),
        cur_url = window.location.href;

    //Check if its already on
    if (! $('.ag_alert_wrapper').is(':visible') ) {

        //Set the language
        (cur_url.indexOf('/en/') >= 0) ? cls_txt = "close" : cls_txt = "閉じる" ;

        $('<div class="ag_mess ag_alert_wrapper"></div><div class="ag_mess ag_alert_wrapper_close">'+ cls_txt +'</div>')
            .prependTo('body');
        $('.ag_alert_wrapper')
            .append('<p>'+ message +'</p>')
            .animate({top : 0}, 200, function() {
                $('.ag_alert_wrapper_close')
                .animate({top : 90}, 200)
                .on({
                    mouseenter : function () {
                        $(this).animate({
                            top : 100
                        }, 200);
                    },
                    mouseleave : function () {
                        $(this).animate({
                            top : 90
                        }, 200);
                    },
                    click : function () {
                        cls_message();
                    }
                });
            });

        //Setups ESC key to close message
        $(document).keydown(function(e) {
            if (e.keyCode === 27) {
                cls_message();
            }
        });

    } else {
        //if Alert is already visible
        $('.ag_alert_wrapper')
            .children('p').html(message)
            .end()
            .effect("highlight", {
                color : '#FF0'
            }, 1000);

        clearTimeout(timer);
    }

}


function cls_message() {
    $('.ag_mess').animate({
        top : -200
    }, 200, function () {
        $('.ag_mess').remove();
    });
}
```

Comment: What's happening? Is `other_function` firing?  Does the data type of `data` match the type of `'condition'`?

Comment: What about is isn't working? Where the rest of your code?

Comment: I don't know what the problem is, but why even set the timeout if you're going to clear it in the else branch of the same function? Why not move the `setTimeout()` into the if branch?

Comment: -1. I know its a little mean to give a minus. But I find that this isn't enough information to answer the question.  
How could you make this question better? Well I think first you should actually explain whats not working. Then you should maybe give us an example of it not working. This is the best way to see if  your maybe using the function in the wrong place. Remember, you can't add a function in (jQuery): $(document).ready({   }); or(mootools): window.addEvent('domready', function() {   });

Comment: Basically this is a alert message. If the target clicked I want to show this message if its hidden and set the 5 second to remove it by it self. If user clicked the same btn while message is open, I want to remove the timer and force them to close the message manually.

Comment: @Jay Thanks for the explanation. Could you make a Jsfiddle. If you do, I take my -1 off. I like jsFiddle because i'm an visual learner. So by reading this, I can't really figure out what it does.

Comment: @Shawn31313 Thanks Shawn, Here is the jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/jonevar/2Z2NQ/5/

Comment: Thanks everybody for your minuses, meanwhile if you can tell me what is the issue would be nice too. Appreciate your kindness.

Comment: Seems to work. Please explain again what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be working fine, test code (using jQuery, but that's not changing the conclusion):

html

```
<div id="msgs"></div>
```

js

```
function other_function() {
    $('#msgs').append('other ');   
}

function do_something(data) {
    var timer = setTimeout(other_function, 500);
    if (data === "condition") {
        $('#msgs').append('hi ');
    } else {
        $('#msgs').append('clearing ');
        clearTimeout(timer);
    }
}

do_something('yay');

do_something('condition');
```

Outputs this to the div:

```
clearing hi other
```

as expected. Live example:

- http://jsfiddle.net/mCdxV/

Hope this helps.

Comment: Would you take a look at the edited post. I just added the whole code.

Comment: There's no `other_function` in the code from what I see - can you make a jsfiddle that shows your problem, otherwise the code you added has a lot of things that are hard to figure out where the problem lies.

Comment: Still too big, but the issue is this - you are calling ag_alert on every click. Every time you are making a new timer, but the one you are cancelling is the one you just made. The one from the previous click is gone out of scope and will fire anyway. One way to make this work is to make a global timer. Here's an example that works: http://jsfiddle.net/2Z2NQ/6/. Also, note I commented `event.preventDefault()` line - I'm using Firefox and it failed there, as this is IE-specific.

Comment: I got my answer. Thanks for your time and help.